# What is the negation of ∀x∃y¬P(x,y) without using ¬?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Found it to be ∃x∀yP(x,y).

Is this right?

Comment: Yes, it is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one possible way of reasoning, passing the $\lnot$ through the quantors:

$\lnot\forall x: \exists y:\lnot P(x,y) ~\Leftrightarrow~ \exists x: \lnot\exists y: \lnot P(x, y) ~\Leftrightarrow~ \exists x : \forall y : \lnot\lnot P(x, y)~\Leftrightarrow~ \exists x : \forall y : P(x,y)$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the answer you gave is right.